# how to prevent binary run from a sudo script from responding to SIGHUP?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that executes a sudo command that runs a script that executes a binary (java). That binary seems to receive SIGHUP when the the login session ends (I run my script in an SSH session from my laptop, so network disconnects when I commute). The SIGHUP causes the binary process to abort.

I tried calling the sudo command with 'nohup' and trapping SIGHUP, with no success. I can't change the sudo command (e.g. 'sudo nohup' instead of 'nohup sudo'), or the script I execute with it (due to security constraints).

What other options exist? I know I can do a double fork, but I want the binary to run in the foreground while the session is live (it is running a query, so when the session is alive, I want to be able to wait for it to finish interactively and see results, but if I hangup, to have it continue to run)

Comment: Which security constraints do you mean?

Comment: I can't change the script executed by sudo or execute another command with sudo